# Copy-on-write modification to shared array

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

Consider a read-only buffer that is shared between N threads. In order to modify the buffer, the requester determines the number of references that exist to the buffer and either copies it or modifies it in-place. In a single-threaded model, the code for this could be written as follows.

```
class buffer_data;

class buffer_view {
    std::shared_ptr<buffer_data> m_ptr;
public:
    const buffer_data *read_ptr() const
    {
        return m_ptr.get();
    }

    buffer_data *try_write_ptr()
    {
        return m_ptr.unique() ? m_ptr.get() : nullptr;
    }

    buffer_data *write_ptr()
    {
        if (!m_ptr.unique())
            m_ptr = std::make_shared<buffer_data>{ *m_ptr };
        return m_ptr.get();
    }
}
```

However, if multiple threads hold references to `buffer_data` through `buffer_view`, a race could occur between checking the reference count in `buffer_view::write_ptr` and another thread acquiring a reference to `buffer_data` by copying the `buffer_view`, resulting in data corruption.

How can I modify this example to be thread-safe? Is `std::shared_ptr` the right construct to use for this, or is there a more effective approach?

EDIT: The desired ownership semantic of buffer_view is that if only one reference exists, the caller of `buffer_view::write_ptr` modifies the existing buffer in-place, but if multiple references exist, it will copy the buffer to a new buffer with one reference.

Comment: There is an example of a cow pointer [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-on-write).

Comment: @Jason, I took a look at that example, but it suffers the same problem. It checks for `unique()` before doing a copy in a separate statement, leading to the same race condition.

Comment: You need to define the consistency semantics for your cow pointer.  If you're modifying the data concurrently, there are potentially other issues as well.  The simplest general solution I can think of would be sequentially consistent using read/write lock semantics.  I don't know what platform you are on though, or what libraries you can use.

Comment: @Jason I added a note about the desired behavior. The main concept is atomically performing the check for unique ownership when multiple threads hold pointers to `buffer_view`. I am able to use the standard library.

Comment: Consistency refers to the ordering of events, which you have to explicitly define when you write multi-threaded code.  Writing a good multi-threaded cow pointer isn't a trivial task.

Comment: It's very simple actually. The idea is for writes to never be visible except to the caller of `write_ptr`, whether that is a thread or a class or some other logical unit. We can lock stuff if that's your concern.